# Streamlit demo file

Tags: python

I am trying to add an example file to my streamlit application for users' demo using this code, but I get this eerror:

TypeError: Smiles Molecule_ChEMBL_ID 0 CNC(=O)c1cc(Oc2ccc(NC(=O) has type DataFrame, but expected one of: bytes, unicode.

Any help?

```
    if st.sidebar.button('Example'):
           mult = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\HP-PC\Desktop\python\demo2.csv")
           uploaded_file = st.sidebar.file_uploader(mult)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should upload the file , then read it as data frame !

```
uploaded_file = st.file_uploader("Choose a file")
# select the path "C:\Users\HP-PC\Desktop\python\demo2.csv"

if uploaded_file is not None:
        mult = pd.read_csv(uploaded_file)
        st.write(mult)
```